# Python: Compare two lists and create a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In Python, I have a list of pairs (**A**) and a list of integers (**B**). A and B always have the **same length**. I want to know of a **fast way** of finding all the elements (pairs) of A  that correspond to the same value in B (by comparison of indices of A and B) and then **store the values in a dictionary** (**C**) (the keys of the dictionary would correspond to elements of B). As an example, if

```
A = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 6), (0, 7), (1, 3), (1, 7)]
B = [  2,      5,      5,       1,      5,     4,       1  ]
```

then

```
C = {1: [(0,6),(1,7)], 2: [(0,0)],  4: [(1,3)], 5[(0,1), (0,3), (0,7)]}
```

Presently, I am trying this approach:

```
C = {}
for a, b in zip(A, B):
    C.setdefault(b, [])
    C[b].append(a)
```

While this approach gives me the desired result, I would like some approach which will be way faster (since I need to work with big datasets). I will be thankful if anyone can suggest a **fast way** to implement this (*i.e.* find the dictionary C once one is in knowledge of lists A and B).

Comment: Is there a reason why it can't be created while `A` and `B` are being populated?

Comment: Other than the redundant `C[b]` lookup (`C.setdefault(b, []).append(a)` is sufficient) I don't think there are a lot of opportunities to increase this speed without using alternative technologies (e.g. PySpark).

Comment: @SiddTheKid I really do not think you will have a better solution for this question since if you see this solution from an BigO notation, it g(n) is n+1 which is approximately equal to o(n).

Comment: Would a `defaultdict` be any better or is it just the same as `setdefault`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: That's a nice thought. The thing is that, though A and B are connected in one way it is not possible to create C while A and B are being populated; at least not very easily. Again, that's a really nice thought

Comment: @AChampion: Thanks for the information. Hmm, I can think of PySpark if it's not too much of work at this stage.

Comment: @Steven Summers: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried both defaultdict and setdefault. For small datasets, I do not see a significant difference in time. I can try for a larger dataset. Maybe the difference is noticeable (and I hope defaultdict will turn out to be better) for larger datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I would have suggested

```
for i in range (0,len(B)):
    C2.setdefault(B[i], [])
    C2[B[i]].append(A[i])
```

it would save the zip (A,B) process

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections
C = collections.defaultdict(list)
for ind, key in enumerate(B):
    C[key].append(A[ind])
```